# Google one tap sign in not working inside mat-dialog

Tags: angular

I am using google one tap and everything works fine if  i render button `<div id="buttonDiv"></div>`
inside `component A` which is the landing screen , but the same code fails to render the button if `component A` contains a `btn` that opens a  mat dialog for component B (where i want the google sign in button too be rendered ).

The difference is in `component A` (landing screen ) `window.onGoogleLibraryLoad` works fine but not when placed inside `component B`

I've tried moving the script from `index.htm`  to page level `component B`

Is there a way to pass that rendered button to a mat dialog like so

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(LoginDialogComponent, { autoFocus: true,data: document.getElementById('buttonDiv') });
```

```
//@ts-ignore
window.onGoogleLibraryLoad = () => {
    console.log('Google\'s One-tap sign in script loaded!');
    //@ts-ignore
    google.accounts.id.initialize({ // this is what goes out to google , which uses clientid to get into google
        client_id: this.clientId,
        callback: this.handleGoogleSSOCredentialsResponse.bind(this), // this callback will return google credentials 
        auto_select: false, // if true automatically selects first account and logs in 
        cancel_on_tap_outside: true
    });
    
    //@ts-ignore
    google.accounts.id.renderButton(
        //@ts-ignore
        document.getElementById('buttonDiv'),
        { theme: 'outline', size: 'large', width: 300 }
    );
    
    //@ts-ignore
    google.accounts.id.prompt((notification: PromptMomentNotification) => {

    });
};
```